# Problem with module for solving wave equation

Tags: differential-equations

Im really new to mathematica and trying to solve a homogeneous wave equation numericallly. I wrote a module for it and wanted to test it but it only returns my input.

```
    SolveWaveCTCS[nn_,xNum_,xDel_,tNum_,tDel,GvRb_]:=Module[
{yNum,yDel,x,y,z,n},

yNum = xNum;
yDel = xDel;
x[i_]=i xDel;
y[j_]=j yDel;
n[j_,k_]=nn[x[j],y[k]];

Clear[z];
GvRb/.Rb[a_,b_,c_]:

z[i_,j_,t_]:=z[i,j,t]=
2 z[i,j,t-1]-z[i,j,t-2]-tDel^2  n[i,j]^2/c^2  xDel^2 (z[i+1,j,t-1]-2 z[i,j,t-1]+z[i-1,j,t-1])-tDel^2  n[i,j]^2/c^2  yDel^2 (z[i,j+1,t-1]-2 z[i,j,t-1]+z[i,j-1,t-1]) /. c->1; 

Return[Table[{i xDel,j yDel,z[i,j,n]//N},{i,0,xNum},{j,0,yNum}]];
];


(*testing the module*)

nn[x_,y_]:=5 *x+4 *y;
xnum = 10;
tnum =1;
xdel=1;
tdel=0.1;
gvbr = List[Rb[0,j_,n_]:=0,
Rb[xnum,j_,n_]:=0,
Rb[i_,0,n_]:=x[i] (1-x[i]) Sin[2 n tdel],
Rb[i_,ynum,n_]:=0];

SolveWaveCTCS[nn,xnum,xdel,tnum,tdel,gvbr]
```

Output: SolveWaveCTCS[nn,10,1,1,0.1,{Null,Null,Null,Null}]

Does someone maybe know why it does not do anything at all? It does not even give me an error.

Comment: At a glance, your `tDel` is missing an underscore...I don't know what you want `gvbr` to be, but its definition seems very odd.

Comment: Ahh i missed that one, thanks a lot. :)